# Understanding convergence of power method

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix. Let its eigenvalues be $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n$ with $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2|>\cdots>|\lambda_n|$ and its corresponding eigenvectors be $\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2, \dots, \vec{v}_n$ (I don't know if they should be normalized). Let $\vec{x}_0$ be an arbitrary vector expressed as an linear combination of eigenvectors:

$$\vec{x}_0=c_1\vec{v}_1+c_2\vec{v}_2+\cdots+c_n\vec{v}_n$$

with $c_1\ne0$. The normalized power method describes the following iteration scheme for each $k\in\mathbb N$:

$$\vec{x}_k=\frac{A\vec{x}_{k-1}}{||A\vec{x}_{k-1}||_\infty}$$

where $||\cdot||_\infty$ is infinity norm. It is not immediately obvious to me why it is true that $\vec{x}_k\to\vec{v}_1$ as $k\to\infty$. It seems like $A\vec{x}_k\to c_1\lambda_1\vec{v}_1$ and $||A\vec{x}_k||\to c_1\lambda_1$ as $k\to\infty$. Why it is true that $||A\vec{x}_k||\to c_1\lambda_1$ as $k\to\infty$?

Comment: Use $x_k = \frac{A^k x_0}{\|A^k x_0\|_{\infty}}$.